# VirtualBox USB Support, USB Drive is NOT working, detected or recognized

Tags: linux, windows, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using latest stable version of [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with `VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack` on `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)` (`Linux 3.10.0`).

My `Virtual Machine`'s `Operating System` is `Windows 8.1` and I enabled following options through VM's `Settings`:

- `Enable USB Controller`
- `Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller`

Yet, VirtualBox USB Support, USB Drive is NOT working, detected or recognized. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Add extension pack from an official website and - if it still non-operational, try VirtualBox OSE compiled from sources. It helps alot - I was in such kind of trouble myself

Comment: "With version 4.0, there is only one version any more, which is open source, and the closed-source components have been moved to a separate extension pack." and as I stated earlier I _ALREADY_ have `Extension Pack` installed.

Comment: The problem is, that the extension pack can be installed on both versions : closed and open one.

Comment: see following: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions